# Runtime '3129' Update Statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm writing in VBA/MS Access and having trouble with this error. I think it's the date. I use the function:

```
DOB = Format(DOB,"\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```

Now this works for the INSERT sql also running in my code. It looks like this when I Debug.Print

```
,#01/01/1900#,
```

My problem is with my UPDATE sql statement.

```
"UPDATE table SET " & "DOB=" & DOB & "," & "Last_Maintain_Date=" & LastMaintainDate & _
"," & LastmaintainUser & " WHERE ID=" & ID
```

Debug.Print

```
UPDATE table SET DOB=#03/01/1983#,Last_Maintain_Date="10/11/2019 2:59:47 PM",Last_Maintain_User="User Name" WHERE ID=11111111
```

DOB is a date field. ID is a numeric field, and the other two are strings. I wish run-time errors would help you a little more than just "your code is wrong".

Comment: I don't see this in your update statement. `Last_Maintain_User=` But it's in the `Debug.Print`.

Comment: The message for error 3129 is *"Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'."*  I don't see a problem with the syntax in the `Debug.Print` of your `UPDATE` statement.  Please show us how you're attempting to execute it.

Comment: @WEI_DBA it's there, it's just a typo, The Debug.Print is what is being sent to the RunSQL command.

Comment: @HansUp I'm storing the value in a string then doing DoCmd.RunSQL SQLstring

Comment: Never store date/time as text, always as _DateTime_.

Comment: `Debug.Print SQLstring` immediately before you call `DoCmd.RunSQL SQLstring` because that `UPDATE` should not trigger error 3129.  `SQLstring` may not contain what you expect.

Comment: @Gustav, the process is importing CSVs files into a temp table, which is mostly just string because then we do a validation, we want all fields to come in as string, then I have to convert it to put it in the production table. That's why it has to be stored as a string first. There is no changing this process, it is what is required.

Comment: @HansUp Debug.Print SQLstring is immediately before the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider parameterization which is supported in MS Access using [QueryDefs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydefs-collection-dao) and helps avoid the need for punctuation or concatenation:

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
Dim qdef As QueryDef

' PREPARED SQL STATEMENT WITH PARAMETERS CLAUSE (NO DATA)
strSQL  = "PARAMETERS [prmDOB] Date, [prmLastMaintainDate] Date, "_
            & "       [prmLastmaintainUser] Text, [prmID] Long;"
            & " UPDATE mytable " _
            & " SET DOB = [prmDOB], " _
            & "     Last_Maintain_Date = [prmLastMaintainDate], " _
            & "     LastmaintainUser = [prmLastmaintainUser] " _
            & " WHERE ID = [prmID]"

Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("", strSQL)

' BIND PARAMS (NO QUOTES OR HASHTAGS)
qdef![prmDOB] = DOB                            ' ASSUMED TO BE A DATE TYPE
qdef![prmLastMaintainDate] = LastMaintainDate  ' ASSUMED TO BE A DATE TYPE 
qdef![prmLastmaintainUser] = LastmaintainUser  ' ASSUMED TO BE A STRING TYPE
qdef![prmID] = ID                              ' ASSUMED TO BE AN INT/LONG TYPE

' RUN ACTION
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

You can even save above update statement as an MS Access stored query and reference it below, entirely divorcing SQL from VBA:

```vb
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedUpdateQuery")

' BIND PARAMS
qdef![prmDOB] = DOB
qdef![prmLastMaintainDate] = LastMaintainDate
qdef![prmLastmaintainUser] = LastmaintainUser
qdef![prmID] = ID

' RUN ACTION    
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

Please note SQL parameterization is a programming industry best practice that extends beyond VBA to *any* application layer that runs SQL as a lower-level language including general purpose languages like Java, Python, C#, PHP, and others. Though implementation differs, concept is the same to separate SQL from application code. See StackOverflow Co-Founder Jeff Atwood's [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/).

Comment: This might be an option, but seems like a lot more code for something I already have set a certain way, and it's probably a simple solution. Just hard to diagnose. But might end up going this way.

Comment: I'm going to vote this as the answer. It is the route I'm currently taking now.

Comment: question. Can I declare say more variables than I may update? Say declare every field in a table, but let's say I only want to update 3 of the fields, I can declare all those other parameters but update the "SET " part of the statement to update only those 3 fields right? Because I'm getting a runtime '3256' error now, Item not in collection.

I have to build this UPDATE     SET statement through code where variables are constantly changing.

Comment: Please ask that on a different thread with more context as there are ways to handle such needs.

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of Last_Maintain_Date is date, then you have to format it the same way as DOB:

Update Table SET  ...  Last_Maintain_Date=#10/11/2019 14:59:47#  ...

Comment: No, Last_Maintain_Date is actually a string.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to quote the text values and the variabel :

```
"UPDATE table SET DOB=" & DOB & "," & "Last_Maintain_Date='" & LastMaintainDate & "'," & _
"Last_Maintain_User = '" LastmaintainUser & "' WHERE ID=" & ID & ""
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not solve the issue. Still getting an error.

Comment: The syntax is correct, so either a field name or value is invalid or you have an offending index.